# Parsing string returned by Telnet.Read_Very_Eager line by line

Tags: python, string, parsing, telnet

In python, how do I parse this into strings?
I expect the output to print each line, lines are found by a newline (\n) delimeter, but all I get are individual characters, for example, if the Server sends "This is a string
this is another one" I get

"T
h
i
s
..."
And so on.

```
from time import sleep
tn = Telnet('myhost',port)
sleep(0.5)
response = tn.read_very_eager()

#How do I do something like this? I tried parsing it using string.split,
#all I got was individual characters.
foreach (line in response):
    print line, "This is a new line"

tn.close()

foreach (line in response):
    print line, "This is a new line"
```

Comment: There's no `foreach` in `Python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF I got your question correctly, it should look like this:

```
from time import sleep

tn = Telnet('myhost', port)
sleep(0.5)

response = tn.read_very_eager()

for line in response.split():
    # Python 3.x version print
    print(line)

    # Python 2.x version print
    # print line

tn.close()
```

UPD: Updated answer according to the comment from OP.